# Ito's Lemma for level set

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Say I have the following level set: $c = f(x,y)$, where $x$ is a stochastic variable, and $y$ is purely deterministic, and of course, $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Does applying Ito's lemma to $c$ make sense? I.e.,

$dc = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} (dx)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} (dy)^2$.

Is it appropriate then, to write $dc = 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: My ideas about these are following. You can interprete $y$ as time, and by implicit function theorem $x$ should be a function of $y$. Though it can be ambigious (in meaning that $y$ is deterministic, and $x$ is random), but you can take $x$ to be also a function of some $\omega$ from the original space. And if the equation above is true for all $\omega$-s (meaning that this is definition), and $c$ is not random (i.e. not dependent of $\omega$), than $x$ also should be non-random. More concisely if $x=g(y,\omega)$ and for all $\omega$-s $c=f(x(y,\omega), y)$ than $c$ must be intuitively random.

Comment: Hi. So, if $c$ is random as you suggest, then, it is not a constant by the definition of level sets? This was my confusion.

Comment: It seem to me. Maybe I get something wrong. However if we fix some $\omega$, we will get by implicit function theorem, what I said above. So I think $c$ should be dependent of $\omega$-s, hence random. But it would be great also to hear other's ideas.